# PySide: Adding a background color to a QGraphicsTextItem object

Tags: highlight, pyside, qgraphicstextitem

Is there a way to **add a background color to a `QGraphicsTextItem`** object?

I've created a `QGraphicsScene`, and need to display text inside it.  I've created a `QGraphicsTextItem` to do the job.  However, it's not very clear against the background, so I'm looking to highlight it, or set a background color to make it more visible.  I haven't found anything in the documentation that does this though.

I'd like to avoid doing this the long way around if there's a better option available.  Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What is the 'long way' you are trying to avoid?

Comment: My 'long way' is to create a `QGraphicsRectItem`, fill it with a color, and have it follow my `QGraphicsTextItem` everywhere it goes.  It would work, but I want to use the better method if one is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

The easiest would be, setting an HTML with the desired style:

```py
htmlItem = QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem()
htmlItem.setHtml('<div style="background:#ff8800;">html item</p>')
```

An alternative approach is subclassing the `QGraphicsTextItem` and doing the custom background with `paint` method.

```py
class MyTextItem(QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, text, background, parent=None):
        super(MyTextItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPlainText(text)
        self.background = background

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # paint the background
        painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QColor(self.background))

        # paint the normal TextItem with the default 'paint' method
        super(MyTextItem, self).paint(painter, option, widget)
```

Here is a basic example demonstrating the both:

```py
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MyTextItem(QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, text, background, parent=None):
        super(MyTextItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPlainText(text)
        self.background = background

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # paint the background
        painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QColor(self.background))

        # paint the normal TextItem with the default 'paint' method
        super(MyTextItem, self).paint(painter, option, widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
    s = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()

    htmlItem = QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem()
    htmlItem.setHtml('<div style="background:#ff8800;">html item</p>')

    myItem = MyTextItem('my item', '#0088ff')

    s.addItem(htmlItem)
    myItem.setPos(0, 30)
    s.addItem(myItem)
    w.setScene(s)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
item = QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem()
item.setFormatTextColor("#value")
```

Comment: It's giving me this error: `AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem' object has no attribute 'setFormatTextColor'`

Comment: Sorry, change 
item.setformatTextColor to item.setDefaultTextColor